# MySQL Cluster Only Sync Partially

Tags: mysql, ndbcluster

I am new to MySQL, but I have to solve this problem quickly.

I installed FileRun (which is a file share service) on two nodes, those two nodes have MySQL Cluster backend.

In Filerun GUI, I created a new user on the primary node, but the secondary one couldn't get the data. However, if I manually create a table and insert a data in the filerun database, the synchronise can proceed.

Here is what I did:

On both **nodeA** and **nodeB**:

```
mysql> use filerun;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> select id,name from df_users;
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Superuser |
+----+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

On **nodeA**, I created a new user via Filerun GUI, I query again and can see the new user has been added:

```
mysql> select id,name from df_users;
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Superuser |
|  9 | test      |
+----+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, on **nodeB**, the table was still not updated.

```
mysql> select id,name from df_users;
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Superuser |
+----+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For the debug purpose, I created a new table on **nodeA** in the same database:

```
mysql> create table students (name VARCHAR(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (2 min 0.82 sec)

mysql> insert students set name="john";
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> select * from students;
+------+
| name |
+------+
| john |
+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Back to **nodeB**, I can see the data has been transferred:

```
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------------+
| Tables_in_filerun     |
+-----------------------+
….omitted….. 
| students              |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.51 sec)

mysql> select * from students;
+------+
| name |
+------+
| john |
+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

At the same time on **nodeB**, this event was popped up by MySQL log(only shows the table replication, I don't know why):

```
2017-09-09T00:40:58.202248Z 1 [Note] NDB Binlog: DISCOVER TABLE Event: REPL$filerun/students
2017-09-09T00:40:58.211230Z 1 [Note] NDB Binlog: logging ./filerun/students (UPDATED,USE_WRITE)
```

Again, I tried to manually insert a data into the "df_users: table on **nodeA**:

```
mysql> insert into df_users (id,name) values("2","Jack");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select id,name from df_users;
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Superuser |
|  2 | Jack      |
|  9 | test      |
+----+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Unfortunately, the **nodeB** still receiving nothing!

```
mysql> select id,name from df_users;
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Superuser |
+----+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any idea about this? How to check the transaction between two nodes?

Other information:
Both two nodes has Ubuntu 14.04 installed.
MySQL is installed locally,version: 5.7.18-ndb-7.6.3-log

```
root@ndb-mgmd:~# ndb_mgm -e show
Connected to Management Server at: localhost:1186
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)] 2 node(s)
id=2    @192.168.0.20  (mysql-5.7.18 ndb-7.6.3, Nodegroup: 0, *)
id=3    @192.168.0.21  (mysql-5.7.18 ndb-7.6.3, Nodegroup: 0)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @192.168.0.30  (mysql-5.7.18 ndb-7.6.3)

[mysqld(API)]   2 node(s)
id=4    @192.168.0.20  (mysql-5.7.18 ndb-7.6.3)
id=5    @192.168.0.21  (mysql-5.7.18 ndb-7.6.3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the storage engine is not using ndbcluster. To address this, we should convert the storage engine. See my another post: [Unable to Convert table Engine from MyISAM to NDBCLUSTER](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185532/unable-to-convert-table-engine-from-myisam-to-ndbcluster)